# strange TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

I have a strange problem parsing this json:

```
{
    "status":"UP",
    "diskSpace": {
        "status":"UP",
        "total":10434699264,
        "free":8502456320,
        "threshold":10485760
    }
}
```

I'm usign the following call im my program:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, ssl, json

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

# Retrieve data
# The context = ctx will ignore the errors from certificates
#url = 'https://www.google.com'
#html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()

with urllib.request.urlopen("url", context=ctx) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read())
    mykey="diskSpace"
    print(data[mykey]['status'])
    for key in data:
        print(key)
        print(type(key))
        print(type(data))
        print(data[mykey]['status'])
        print(type(data[key]))
        print(data[key]['status'])
```

I got the folowing output:

```
$ python3 test.py
UP
status
<class 'str'>
<class 'dict'>
UP
<class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(data[key]['status'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Why is python considering `data[key]` as a string ?

I'm having troubles finding the issue.

Comment: Apparently `data[key]` is a string, so `data[key]['status']` causes an error since string indices cannot be strings.

Comment: It would be helpful if you put print statement output against the print statements as a comment. `data[key]` is a string and not `dict`

Comment: sorry I found it. in the first iteration of the loop key=status which is not a dict...

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code :

```
data={
    "status":"UP",
    "diskSpace": {
        "status":"UP",
        "total":10434699264,
        "free":8502456320,
        "threshold":10485760
    }
}

for key in data:
    print('key=', key)
    print('data[key]=', data[key])
    print('type(data[key])=', type(data[key]))
    print('\n')
```

which leads to this answer:

```
key= status
data[key]= UP
type(data[key])= <class 'str'>


key= diskSpace
data[key]= {'status': 'UP', 'total': 10434699264, 'free': 8502456320, 'threshold': 10485760}
type(data[key])= <class 'dict'>
```